# (Tkinter) Get height of frame before it is packed

Tags: python, tkinter

As the title suggests, I'm wondering if it's possible to get the height of a frame full of widgets before it is packed and displayed.

Here is some example code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='green')

label = tk.Label(frame, text='hello')
label.pack(side='top')

button = tk.Button(frame, text='Test Button')
button.pack(side='top')

print(frame['height']) # Outputs 0

frame.pack(side='top')

root.mainloop()
```

I want to be able to do this so that if the frame is taller than a specific threshold, it will instead go inside a scrollable canvas.

Thanks.

Comment: Use `frame.update()` then use: `print(frame.winfo_reqheight())`, outputs 47 for me.

Comment: @TheLizzard Thanks, this works. I want to ask though - why did you reply with a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: Well the solution was simple and I didn't think it needed an explanation. Do you want me to explain what the `.update` and the `.winfo_reqheight` do in a proper answer?

Comment: @TheLizzard No, you don't have to, I can look into it myself thank you. I will answer my own question in case someone with the same problem finds this post but misses the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in TheLizzard's comment, I can do this by using the following code:

```py
...
frame.update()
print(frame.winfo_reqheight())

frame.pack(side='top')
...
```